# How to remove space in vertical for the showMenu function?

Tags: flutter

I use the `showMenu` function to show menus with dialog.
My code is

```
      const width = 100.0;
      const height = 40.0;
      await showMenu(
        items: [
          PopupMenuItem(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: Container(width: width, height: height, color: Colors.blue, child: const Text('test 1'))),
          PopupMenuItem(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: Container(width: width, height: height, color: Colors.blue, child: const Text('test 2'))),
        ],
        context: context,
        position: const RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height * 2),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
        color: Colors.red,
      );
```

I tried to fit it by setting the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` of the `constraints` property in the `showMenu`, the horizontal is working but the vertical still has space between menus.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `height` of each `PopupMenuItem` to 0.

```dart
PopupMenuItem(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  height: 0,
  child: Container(
    width: width,
    height: height,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: const Text('test 1')
  )
),
PopupMenuItem(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  height: 0,
  child: Container(
    width: width,
    height: height,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: const Text('test 2')
  )
),
```

Result:

[image]

Note: You can't remove the top space because that widget is using a "_kMenuVerticalPadding = 8." by default and there is no way to change unless you implement your own widget.

Comment: OMG, why I don't see this? Thank you so much. Now, how do we remove that top space?

Comment: you can't remove the top space because that widget is using a "_kMenuVerticalPadding = 8."  by default and there is no way to change unless you implement your own widget.

Comment: You can mark this question as resolved if my answer was helpful :)

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain that we can't remove top space  because..... for make this answer completely for someone like me that tried to find the solution to remove top space and this anwer will told them to stop waste time for find this solution.

Comment: Ok, Updated ;) ...